# Specifying multiple class path jars in a unix terminal command

Tags: java, unix

I can't seem to get this to work from a unix terminal

```
java -cp a.jar;b.jar ...
```

I know that this works:

```
java -c "./*" ...
```

But python doesn't know how to recognize and recover the output of a wildcard statement. Is there a way to explicitly state the class path jars in a unix terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong path separator for unix based java.

Try

```
java -cp a.jar:b.jar ...
```